# How to enlarge custom slide in slick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I want to know how to enlarge specific slide in slick gallery. I want to enlarge slide with class *toEnlarge*. I tried with scalling, adding padding, margin, etc., but no effect. Any idea?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="slick-holder">
   <a href="link.html">
       <div class="single"></div>
   </a>
   <a href="link.html" class="toEnlarge">
       <div class="single"></div>
   </a>
   ...
   <a href="link.html">
       <div class="single"></div>
   </a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.slick-holder').slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: true,
});
```

I'm trying to do something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like?

```
.toEnlarge{
  display: block;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: I did. But it enlarges only at left, right and bottom. Top remains the same.

Comment: have you found a solution?